# execcommand("SaveAs",null,"file.csv") is not working in IE8

Tags: javascript

```
var doc = w.document;
doc.open('application/CSV','replace');
doc.charset = "utf-8";
doc.write("all,hello");
doc.close();

if(doc.execCommand("SaveAs",null,"file.csv")) {
    window.alert("saved ");
}else {
    window.alert("cannot be saved");
}
```

not working in IE 8

but woks in IE 6

what is the problem ? it is alerting "cannot be saved"

help me !!! advance thanks

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-NZ/iewebdevelopment/thread/1b8bfc9d-0746-4bc4-b7ca-9ebe3132877b

Comment: This is almost certainly a permissions problem. Where is this code coming from?  In other words, what is the URL for the page that has this code in it?

Comment: html table is in one html file & the above code is coming from the javascript file which is in javascript directory (/js/bug_list.js)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem seems to be caused by an old bug that was fixed in Windows XP but is apparently unpatched in my Windows 7.  From http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929863:

> This problem occurs because of a limitation in the **ExecCommand** function. When you run the script that uses the **ExecCommand** function together with the **SaveAs** command, the script can only save a file that is the text file type.

Sure enough, change the file extension to ".txt" and watch it magically work in IE8.

The only workaround that comes to mind is to have a server-side language create the CSV file, and serve it up as a download (using the `Content-disposition: attachment` header).

Comment: As you said it is working when we save it as "txt". if you guys find any trick then you can post the idea as i have to be done it from client side!! advance thanks

Comment: http://4umi.com/web/javascript/filewrite.php check out this link and if possible help me

Comment: @Anbu: are you running the page from the local filesystem and only in IE? If so, it's possible you could use an ActiveX control (namely, FileSystemObject) to write the CSV file.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ee7s9w2(VS.85).aspx for more info.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an very old thread, but I also faced this problem.
You can fix it by adding the following value (depending on the extension of the file beeing downloaded) to your registry.

E.g. for .csv file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.csv]
"PerceivedType"="document"
```

@MICROSOFT: Shame on you; problem seems to be still unpatched :-)

Comment: It works like a charm. I had the same issue but in my case it was working in some system and wasn't working in some systems.

Answer (score 0):

If you could do this processing server side with PHP or .NET or Java or something, in the http headers set:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv
```

Which, unfortunately you can't do from JavaScript.

Comment: thanks for the timly reply!! 
but i cant do anything in serverside so please give a solution in client side. 
Is there any specific reason that it will not work in IE8 ?

Comment: Try Andy E's suggestion, change the file extension to txt.