# ShellClass.BrowseForFolder(...) DialogBox not showing

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `.aspx` page in my project inside that there is one `<a>` link for download `.txt` files.

Am using `Shell32.ShellClass` and `Shell32.Folder2` for showing **Browse For Folder** for ask user to Where do you want to save files instead it download on default `Downloads` folder.

Below is my `C#` code for showing DialogBox.

```
Shell32.ShellClass shell = new Shell32.ShellClass();
            Shell32.Folder2 flder = (Shell32.Folder2)shell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Select destination folder", 0,"Desktop");
            if (flder == null)
            {
                dlgResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
            }
            else
            {
                strPath = flder.Self.Path;
                dlgResult = DialogResult.OK;                
                File.WriteAllText(strPath + "\\NewFile.txt", "file content abc tex...");
            }
```

**Problem:** Above code working fine in Local **but when I host website on IIS** it's not working and not showing DialogBox.

Is there any specific Settings or Configurations in IIS for that ? or why it's not working when it host in IIS?

please give me suggestions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your C# code runs on the server, not in the web page. When you open a dialog box in this way, it runs in the context of the calling code. When running as part of IIS express (or any web server running as you), it opens in your Windows desktop because it is running as you. When running in IIS, it is running as a different account not attached to your desktop, so it will not show.

I am not aware of a way to invoke the "Save As" functionality to save a file to a different folder in JavaScript. The [execCommand](http://help.dottoro.com/ljcvtcaw.php) function may work but it varies from browser to browser. Some versions of [Internet Explorer also limit what file types can be downloaded this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515791/execcommandsaveas-null-file-csv-is-not-working-in-ie8).