# Saving Base64 encoded PDF with Internet Explorer 10 and below

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, pdf-generation

I have recently started using [Bootstrap Table](http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table/docs/index.html) and the [export plugin](http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table/docs/extensions.html#export) for it. A problem I came across is that the export plugin doesn't work for IE, because the files are output using Data URI, which IE doesn't support (I think I read that IE 11 supports it, but no one in my organization uses IE 11, of course.).

The only file types I am interested in exporting are Microsoft office types (Word, Excel) and PDFs.
I have created a functioning workaround for the MS files.

```
  if (supportsDataUriNavigation())
    window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-' + defaults.type + ';filename=exportData.doc;' + base64data);
  else {
    var iframe = document.getElementById("dataFrame");
    iframe = iframe.contentWindow || iframe.contentDocument;
    iframe.document.open("text/html", "replace");
    iframe.document.write(excelFile);
    iframe.document.close();
    iframe.focus();

    iframe.document.execCommand("SaveAs", true, defaults.fileName + fileExtension);
  }
```

In this check, if the browser is IE, then I use the code I found [here](https://gist.github.com/snekse/8483503431b50b87db5c). This works great for the MS file types, but when I try to do the same for the PDF file, it tries to save as a .htm file. This file is blank. If I replace the fileExtension variable with .pdf in my code, the SaveAs window will not display when I click to export. There are no javascript errors.

I set the src attribute of an embed tag to a string that is returned by the plugin javascript, and it looks like so: `'application/pdf;base64,' + Base64.encode(buffer)`

Anyone know of any solution/workaround?

Comment: I know this is ancient but I'm running into the same issue, trying to save a jsPdf-created PDF in IE9. Apparently only .txt and .htm files work: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2516054/865967

Answer (score 3):

I know this is very old question, but I found the solution and I want to share anyone who has the same problem. You can see the demo here :
https://jsfiddle.net/quangminh_ln/hy36tnt6/

```
'use strict';

var data = "...Your PDF base64 string...";
var fileName = "your_file_name";
if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) { // IE workaround
    var byteCharacters = atob(data);
    var byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
        byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
    var blob = new Blob([byteArray], {type: 'application/pdf'});
    window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, fileName);
}
else { // much easier if not IE
    window.open("data:application/pdf;base64, " + data, '', "height=600,width=800");
}
```

The link that I saw for my solution : https://viethoblog.wordpress.com/2016/08/30/loaddisplay-pdf-from-base64-string-bonus-ie-workaround/

Comment: For IE what version? This is "false" for < 10 ... window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob