# how to display base64 encoded pdf in IE?

Tags: pdf, base64

I’m  try to display pdf file which is embedded using base64 encoding in an html.

Below is the code I have written for this. The pdf file is displayed in chrome  and firefox but not internet explorer.
Any Idea how to get it working in IE?

```
<object data="data:application/pdf;base64,Base64String =" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%"/>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving Base64 encoded PDF with Internet Explorer 10 and below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27154606/saving-base64-encoded-pdf-with-internet-explorer-10-and-below)

Answer (score 6):

I believe the correct answer is you can't.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848897(v=vs.85).aspx

Base64 encoding in IE only works for certain image types and not PDF.