# Base64 encoded PDF file open in IE 10 programmatically

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, pdf

I have the below `base64` encoded string which contains the `pdf` file. When I try to open the file in Chrome/FF using `var url = 'data:application/pdf;base64,' + base64encodedString; window.open(url, '_blank');`, works fine but the same is not working in IE 10. Any help would be appreciated for viewing the corresponding base64 encdoded pdf file in IE.

```
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
```

Comment: you cant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27952123/how-to-display-base64-encoded-pdf-in-ie

Comment: or maybe.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11415665/save-base64-string-as-pdf-at-client-side-with-javascript

Comment: Either of them does not work :(

Comment: figured, if you wana support ie you'll have to do it serverside.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=making+pdf+with+php+tutorial&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8