# Window.open works fine with Chrome. But I want to either make it work in IE or force download the document

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I have a Bas64 encoded string for a pdf document coming from the back-end. Which I use window.open function to open it in Chrome. I know IE doesn't open the same in a new tab or any file over 32kb or any document other than images and few file types. Is there a way to open/download this document in IE?

```
window.open("data:application/pdf;base64," + base64string);
```

Comment: What version(s) of IE? Because the limit was increased to 4GB in IE9... A workaround for IE could be to create a link with that URI, then add code to trigger the click event...

Comment: Did you google [1](https://www.google.com/search?q=data%3Aapplication%2Fpdf%3Bbase64) [2](https://www.google.com/search?q=data%3Aapplication%2Fpdf%3Bbase64+IE)?  Related [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27952123/how-to-display-base64-encoded-pdf-in-ie) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12092633/pdf-js-rendering-a-pdf-file-using-a-base64-file-source-instead-of-url) [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805330/opening-pdf-string-in-new-window-with-javascript), [4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11415665/save-base64-string-as-pdf-at-client-side-with-javascript)