# Very slow load of pdf's in Edge browser

Tags: microsoft-edge, pdf.js

I have an app using pdf.js that works very well in Chrome, Safari and Firefox. It also works in Edge, except the loading times of PDFJS.getDocument is extremely long - minutes. I fetch the file from firebase storage and as far as I can read from the Edge network logger, getting it from firebase is just a few seconds.

I can read from the pdf.js documentation the support for Edge is limited, but I don't know what that mean. Anybody have similar experience with Edge and maybe a solution?

Comment: But... Edge natively shows pdfs? So does chrome. And firefox (which uses pdf.js natively). Why not use the native facilities of the browser? I'd guess you're placing it in an element, but you can switch the element out for a iframe with a URL pointing to the document...

Comment: @Gøngevangen if you are still looking for a solution I just added a solution for Edge [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52783009/3590235)